# How to pass parameter to xsl using xslt processor?

Tags: xslt

I am getting an empty result when trying to pass a parameter to my stylsheet using the php xslt processor. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

PHP:

```
<?php 
$xsl = new DomDocument();
$xsl->load("style_listgastro.xsl");
$inputdom = new DomDocument();
$inputdom->load("XXX");
$proc = new XsltProcessor();
$xsl = $proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
$xsl = $proc->setParameter(null, 'k', $_GET['k']);
$newdom = $proc->transformToDoc($inputdom);
print $newdom->saveXML();
?>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:td="urn:schemas-XXX:Relationen">
<xsl:param name="k" />
<xsl:template match="/td:Relationen">
...
<xsl:apply-templates select="td:Benutzer_zu_Gastro">
<xsl:sort select="td:Gastroname"></xsl:sort>
</xsl:apply-templates>
...
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="td:Benutzer_zu_Gastro">
<xsl:if test="td:Kategorien = '{$k}'">
<li><a>
<xsl:attribute name="href">XXX</xsl:value-of>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="td:Gastroname"></xsl:value-of>
</a></li>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is incorrect:

```
<xsl:if test="td:Kategorien = '{$k}'">
```

it's not comparing `td:Kategorien` against the value of `$k`, but against the string value `{$k}` (and I'm guessing that `td:Kategorien` will never have the value `{$k}`). Instead, just use this:

```
<xsl:if test="td:Kategorien = $k">
```

Or, a better fix would be to change the `apply-templates` line to this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="td:Benutzer_zu_Gastro[td:Kategorien = $k]">
```

and remove the `xsl:if` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `''` instead of `null` as the first argument for `setParameter()`?